# Not finding "Terminal: Manage Workspace Shell Permissions" in command palette

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running VS Code Insiders on Windows 10 and using WSL for the integrated terminal. I'm trying (without success) to set environment variables in settings.json that will be available in the terminal. According to the documentation here - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuration - I need to have the appropriate permissions set first but I can't find where to set them. The command "Terminal: Manage Workspace Shell Permissions" doesn't find anything. How might I do this?
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same issue today.

After some frustrations I stumbled upon the
`"terminal.integrated.allowWorkspaceConfiguration": true`
setting, which must be added to the User Settings. - That did the trick for me - hope my answer helps!

Best Regards,
luke